# Even though one of the fields is not required and when you don't enter it the form is still invalid

Tags: angular

Even though one of the fields is not required and when you don't enter it the form is
still invalid. I'm trying in it but it is not working.

**app.component.html**

```
    <form [formGroup]="multiSelectForm">
       <div formGroupName="A">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
          <mat-label>a1</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="a1">
              <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of fakeArray">{{ item }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
          <mat-label>a2</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="a2">
            <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of fakeArray">{{ item }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
         <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
           <mat-label>a3</mat-label>
           <mat-select formControlName="a3">
             <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of fakeArray">{{ item }}
             </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </form>

    {{multiSelectForm.valid | json}}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class MultiSelectReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {
  multiSelectForm: FormGroup;
  fakeArray = []
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.fakeArray = ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']
    this.multiSelectForm = this.fb.group({
      A: this.fb.group({
       a1: ['', Validators.required],
       a2: [''],
       a3: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  })
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting the required fields to an empty string value, which does not satisfy the "required" validator.

If you select a value in each of the required fields, you will see the status will become valid.

If you want the initial state of the form to be valid, you can initialize to a different value:

```js
 a1: ['z1', Validators.required],
 a2: [''],
 a3: ['z2', Validators.required]
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71849183?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I tried this solution on the original project but the problem still exists

Comment: Something must be different. Try to reproduce in a new stackblitz.